# How to Keep Input Cells Hidden After Evaluating Notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, slideshows

I've created a notebook for use in an in-class presentation. There is a fair amount of MMA code, and my students know nothing about MMA nor do they need to. I don't want to distract them with the code. I understand how to collapse the input cells and show only the output, but the input cells expand whenever I evaluate the notebook so I'm back to where I started.

This notebook is meant to be interactive, so it has to be evaluated whenever I change the input. In this case, I have an InputField that requests a ticker symbol and then the code uses FinancialData to get the data and from that creates the results.

I've tried creating a slideshow, but that has the same behavior. I've looked at the resources and answer in "[Best way to give presentations with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61/best-way-to-give-presentations-with-mathematica)" without finding any mention of this issue.

So, in MMA 8.04 is there any way to force the input cells to stay hidden after the notebook is evaluated? Surely, there must be an option for this somewhere.

Comment: How are you collapsing the input cells? In my version of Mathematica if I close an input cell (by delecting `Cell > Cell Properties > Open`) the cell stays closed during and after evaluation.

Comment: @Heike clearly the problem is we are missing the **delecting** key. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard maybe it will be introduced in version 9

Comment: @Heike, that was exactly the problem. I wasn't aware of that command. Thanks.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi, thanks for the pointer. Glad to know that I'm not alone.

Comment: Sorry about this, i have no answer, but i can't comment yet. Mr.Wizard's answer is genious, but it's it possible AutoCollapse doesn't work, if 2 or more Print[]-functions are in the input?

Comment: Another way to do this is to give cells that you want to hide a specific CellTag. CellTags can be set using `SetOptions` and `EvaluationCell` is then a nice tool. `CellTags` will be stored in your notebook, so once you have set them, there is no need to reset them all the time. Cells with a certain CellTag can be found using `Cells`. This allows you to close such cells (again using `SetOptions`) for example.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### `AutoCollapse[]` function

Please try this code, based on Sasha's adaption of my own answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908111/618728).

```
AutoCollapse[] := (
  If[$FrontEnd =!= $Failed, 
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];
   FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]])
```

Then in a new cell:

```
2 + 2
AutoCollapse[]
```

Always place `AutoCollapse[]` as the last line of an Input cell.

### Stylesheets

To get the behavior without having to include `AutoCollapse[]` in each cell you can use [Stylesheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html) and [`CellEpilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEpilog.html).  For example to create an `InputHidden` style use menu **Format** > **Edit Stylesheet...** and then add a Cell with the following code (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to edit Cell code):

```
Cell[StyleData["InputHidden", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Input"]],
 CellEpilog :> (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell]; 
   FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]),
 MenuSortingValue -> 1510
 , MenuCommandKey -> "8"
]
```

[image]

This creates a new style that behaves like Input but which auto-collapses when evaluated.  `MenuCommandKey -> "8"` lets it be quickly applied using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>; change or remove this line as desired.

---

I may be reading more into your question than is there.  As Heike points you can close the input cells manually by deselecting menu `Cell > Cell Properties > Open` but I assumed you knew this already and provided the soluition(?) above.  If all you need is a hidden cell that generates output, use the menu.  If you need something a little more flexible that automatically hides after you make your changes I hope you will find the methods above useful.

Comment: Oooh, that seems to work great! The only problem, easily fixable, is that it changes the background color of my output to transparent (or at least to the background color of the stylesheet - I'm using Creative NaturalColor). I can fix this by explicitly specifying Background -> White for my charts. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim I used `Print` which is a bit hacking, and that is probably what causes the difference.  For my own curiosity I would like to know whether `AutoCollapse` or `Cell > Cell Properties > Open` is closer to the intention of your question.

Comment: @Tim I only now tried that in a different style sheet.  It looks rather ugly, but I think I have a fix. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: as a newbie I didn't know about Cell > Cell Properties > Open, but that appears to do exactly what I need. The input cells stay closed unless I explicitly open them. I think this is perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @Tim I am glad you have a solution.  If in the future you need `AutoCollapse` I think that is working well now too.

Comment: [Closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38041/4330) and perhaps interesting for Mr.W :). Perhaps you could explain the precaution `$FrontEnd =!= $Failed`, I forgot about that when posting my answer.

Comment: @Jacob I copied that directly from Sasha's code.  I believe it is simply to keep the `AutoCollapse` core code from running when it is evaluated outside of a Notebook interface, for example if you saved the Notebook as a Package.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this doesn't work with Mathematica 10.0.

Comment: @Thomas I just tried this and it seems to be working properly in version 10.0.0 under Windows.  What OS are you running and what was your exact input?

Comment: I have the latest OSX 10.9.4. Basically nothing changes, when I run, the results is shown in the out cell and additionally a `Null`(the function return value) is printed. I tried using it both with semicolon and without.. any idea?

Comment: @ThomasFankhauser I tried this with OSX 10.9.3 and MMA10 and it works, so the problem could be local to your computer.

Comment: How to programtically deselect the output cell that is selected with `SelectionMove` after group is closed?

Comment: @dahnoak To move the cursor to the cell insertion point after the output please try: `AutoCollapse[] := (If[$FrontEnd =!= $Failed, 
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];
   FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell];
   ])`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much!

Answer (score 16):

You could <kbd>alt</kbd>-click an output bracket which will cause all output brackets to be selected and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-} to close all subgroups, which, in this case, will close all input brackets that had output.

Alternatively, you could select all outputs in this way and check the menu item `Cell>Grouping Close All Unselected`

Comment: the `alt`-click is awesome! I've never known this!

Answer (score 5):

This might be a good time to use `Dynamic` objects that will update as required with controls, buttons, or `UpdateInterval`, leaving direct evaluation of cells for outside of class.

Comment: That would be a good idea, except that I don't need frequent evaluation. I just need to evaluate at the beginning of the lecture so that we have up-to-date data (and maybe a couple of other times to show that the results aren't a fluke). Of course, I could give up on the fresh data and go with slightly stale data so that I don't need to evaluate at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have found using stylesheets allows you to have tabs to open and close at will. So, if you close the tab with all your code in it, the notebook will compile and the tabs with code will still remain closed. Hope I answered the question.

Comment: I do not find this answer clear.  Would you please update it with additional detail or examples?

Comment: I agree. A minimum requirement would be a link to the style sheet that does all this.