# How to toggle visibility of all the evaluatable cells (but not their output)?

Tags: front-end, display

I know that I can select individual evaluatable cells and disable their `Open` property (through `Cell > Cell Properties`), but is there a simple way to toggle the `Open` status of all evaluatable cells?

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/), [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6809) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15441/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? (V9 and after only, because of [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cells.html).)

```
toggleCellOpen[nb_: SelectedNotebook[]] :=
 (CurrentValue[#, CellOpen] = Not@CurrentValue[#, CellOpen]) & /@ 
   Select[Cells[], CurrentValue[#, Evaluatable] &]
```