# Saving code as a blackbox for wolfram player

Tags: gui-construction, interface, user-interface, wolfram-player

I am trying to save my program as a blackbox so those who I am deploying it to are able to use it, but there is no reason for them to have the huge chunk of code beforehand to have to scroll through.

When it comes to the User Interface I like the way that the following looks:

```
CreateDialog[Manipulate[CODE]]
```

But it doesn't appear that I can save that output. Currently I am using:

```
CreateWindow[Manipulate[CODE]]
```

but I really don't like the way that the output looks being that it is in a notebook rather than a standard window/dialog. Does anybody have any handy tricks to output a good looking UI that is also save-able for Wolfram Player?

Comment: I know there were some recent changes to How WolframPlayer works, so I’m not sure if this is still valid, but I often just double-click on the cell marker for the output. If you double-click on the cel marker that contains both the code and output, you’ll end up hiding the output instead. There’s a nice image [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/is-there-a-way-to-hide-or-toggle-the-visibility-of-code).

Comment: `CDFDeploy[ CreateFile[], CreateDialog[Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}]] ]` or `NotebookSave` or `Export`. Is that the answer?

Comment: @Kuba yes that's exactly what I'm going for. Unfortunately after saving+running it, it asks to "Enable Dynamics" and for some reason it seems to break some of the text boxes(https://ibb.co/VqdRht4), any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I just needed to manually set the size of the button. Thank you!