# How to hide a cell with multiple output?

Tags: cells

i'm working on a presentation using a Mathematica notebook. I'd like to hide the code i wrote.

I found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38041/hide-input-with-multiple-output-cells) and red [this guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithCells.html).

After 7 years from that first answer that hacky method is still the way to go?

What i am trying to do, to be clear is, given this code:

```
A = {
   {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
   {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
   {0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
   };
b = {4, 2, 3, 6};
Print[StringForm["A = ``", MatrixForm[A]]];
Print[StringForm["b = ``", MatrixForm[b]]];
Print[StringForm["``x = ``", MatrixForm[A], MatrixForm[b]]];
```

Show only the output from the 3 Print.

Comment: Would switching between a "Working" and "Presentation" screen environment work for you? You would switch between the two using the `Format | Screen Environment` menu, and you could also add a hot key to switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1: You make some code

[image]

step 2: you select the sell

[image]

step 3: You go to Menu/Cell/CellProperties and uncheck "Open"

[image]

Done.

Have fun!