# Close all the generated cells in a cell group

Tags: front-end

I have tried to insert the AutoCollapse command defined in this nice answer

[How to Keep Input Cells Hidden After Evaluating Notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/680/how-to-keep-input-cells-hidden-after-evaluating-notebook/683#683)

inside a Button

```
  Button["Input Délétion OK", 
  AutoCollapse[] := (If[$FrontEnd =!= $Failed, 
  SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];
  FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]])]
  AutoCollapse[]
```

But AutoCollapse[] stay blue and unevaluated or is evaluated and then unevaluated --- MA 10.1. Any idea ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do want a button that can enable and perhaps disable the action of having `AutoCollapse[ ]` as the last evaluation item in a multi-expression input cell?

Comment: Mainly, I want to hide the code, but I do not want to to it globaly but after verification of each input.

Comment: AutoCollapse is not defined unless you click a button. And button itself does not evaluate `AutoCollapse[]` so I'm quite confused why it was left outside. Can you clarify?