# Delete output cell content but not the space assigned

Tags: output-formatting, slideshows

I'm writing a slide show in Mathematica, and so have Input and Output cells. I want to hide the Output cells until they are generated, but with leaving the space there. Else when I evaluate each cell the ones below jump around.

If I delete the text inside the Output cell it is no longer connected to the Input cell above. Is this possible?

Comment: Somewhat related: [(680)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/680/121)

Comment: That's useful to read, thanks @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to have a function create a toggler that resets to the invisible state when the notebook is closed. Here is a function that does this:

```
hideOnClose /: MakeBoxes[hideOnClose[expr_], fmt:StandardForm] := Module[{i=1},
    TemplateBox[
        {MakeBoxes[expr,fmt]},
        "Hide",
        DisplayFunction -> (TogglerBox[
            Dynamic[i],
            {1 -> PaneBox[#, ImageSize->Scaled[1]], 2->""},
            DynamicBox[ToBoxes[i], Deinitialization:>(i=2)],
            ImageSize->All, Alignment->Center]
        &),
        InterpretationFunction->(#&)
    ]
]
```

The simplest way to implement this is to use:

```
$PrePrint = hideOnClose
```

Using [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) means that you can refer to [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html) and the `hideOnClose` wrapper won't cause trouble. As an example, suppose you evaluate:

```
Graphics[{Red,Circle[]}]
$PrePrint =.
2+2
```

[image]

After closing the notebook, and reopening, you will see:

```
Graphics[{Red,Circle[]}]
$PrePrint =.
2+2
```

[image]

The red circle has disappeared, but the 2+2 output has not because I unset the `$PrePrint` first. One might consider using a custom style in a style sheet instead, eg., "HideInput" with a [`CellProlog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellProlog.html) and [`CellEpilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEpilog.html) that sets and unsets [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html). Then, use "HideInput" for cells you want to hide.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it does exactly what I want. I'll leave it another day to see if anyone else answers.