# Hiding inputs with specific function

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I believe this question could be a duplication, but I did some searches with the term "hide the input cell", but none answered me. Only inputs with this function.

I have several input cells using the [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) function of our colleague [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs).

I am creating some PDF files using this function, but at the moment I was exporting to this type of format I would like these inputs to be hidden.

[image]

How should I proceed?

Comment: When I wrote a presentation where I relied a lot on MaTeX, I used `AutoCollapse` from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/683/731) answer. After having appended it to each cell with MaTeX in them, the cells hid themselves after evaluation, which was really nice because then I could see immediately what the final presentation was going to look like. Others will have to answer how to hide cells only on export...

Comment: Is temporarily helping me. I run the `AutoCollapse` in a Notebook (taking advantage of the memory) and I run in my main file. A little beginner but I'm enjoying it...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See Mr.Wizard's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/683/45431) to [How to Keep Input Cells Hidden After Evaluating Notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/680/45431) where he defines an `AutoCollapse[]` function.

Comment: @CarlWoll Really duplicate. Sorry. I expected Mr.Wizard to publish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For easy searching I copied the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/683/37895) from Mr. Wizard

### `AutoCollapse[]` function

Please try this code, based on Sasha's adaption of my own answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908111/618728).

```
AutoCollapse[] := (
  If[$FrontEnd =!= $Failed, 
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];
   FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]])
```

Then in a new cell:

```
2 + 2
AutoCollapse[]
```

Always place `AutoCollapse[]` as the last line of an Input cell.

### Stylesheets

To get the behavior without having to include `AutoCollapse[]` in each cell you can use [Stylesheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html) and [`CellEpilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEpilog.html).  For example to create an `InputHidden` style use menu **Format** > **Edit Stylesheet...** and then add a Cell with the following code (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to edit Cell code):

```
Cell[StyleData["InputHidden", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Input"]],
 CellEpilog :> (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell]; 
   FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]),
 MenuSortingValue -> 1510
 , MenuCommandKey -> "8"
]
```

[image]

This creates a new style that behaves like Input but which auto-collapses when evaluated.  `MenuCommandKey -> "8"` lets it be quickly applied using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>; change or remove this line as desired.

---

I may be reading more into your question than is there.  As Heike points you can close the input cells manually by deselecting menu `Cell > Cell Properties > Open` but I assumed you knew this already and provided the soluition(?) above.  If all you need is a hidden cell that generates output, use the menu.  If you need something a little more flexible that automatically hides after you make your changes I hope you will find the methods above useful.

Comment: I think it would be much better to reference Mr.Wizards answer rather than copying it verbatim here.