# shorcut key of Cell->Cell Properties->Open

Tags: cells

Is there a shortcut key to control the Open property of cell?

Thanks! [image]

Comment: There is one for open/close cell group: `Command`+`'`. Not the same but similar and possibly useful for similar purposes.

Comment: Dear Szabolcs, thanks, but I did not get "Commnad +'". I want to transform the notebook to PPT, so I have many code to hide. Wish I can use a shortcut directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have find an answer which is really helpfull: AutoCollapse[] function ([Hiding inputs with specific function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149298/hiding-inputs-with-specific-function/149879#149879))

---

Also have find the way of add shortcut button ([Create custom shortcut to change font color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/create-custom-shortcut-to-change-font-color)).

Through change:
MenuItem["&Open", CellOpen->Toggle, Scope->SelectionCell],
to, e.g.
MenuItem["&Open", CellOpen->Toggle, Scope->SelectionCell, MenuKey["0", Modifiers->{"Control"}]]

The figure is shown bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While not directly a shortcut, you can always traverse the menu: <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>