# Sort slides for a presentation

Tags: slideshows

Powerpoint has a Slide Sorter view which I routinely use for (re)organizing a presentation. I can't find something like that in *Mathematica* in the documentation nor online. I very much like the tips given at [Best way to give presentations with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61/best-way-to-give-presentations-with-mathematica) 
but that reference doesn't mention the slide sorter feature which I find hard to do without.

Does anyone know if there's such a view or its equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this response it seems the only way to do it is to copy and paste and then split into a new slide.

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/963668