# Resources for learning how to make SlideShows with Mathematica

Tags: formatting, reference-request, slideshows

I have looked at fantastic answers given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61/best-way-to-give-presentations-with-mathematica) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26629/tips-on-giving-a-lecture-course-using-mathematica?noredirect=1&lq=1). 
My question however is a bit different,  I wanted to find resources that will guide through more technical stuff that is concerned with creating presentation. Looking at this wonderfully made slide show on [graphs & networks](http://www.wolfram.com/training/videos/DAT021/) you can see masterfull formatting of the text. The first thing that I couldn't manage was writing the subtitle namely - the name of the presenter way below the title. The second contents page also holds a surprise. I wanted to know how one can create such presentations.