# Where can I find good examples of Mathematica presentations

Tags: slideshows

I'm beginning to prepare a scientific presentation. As most of my work has been done on Mathematica, I was wondering about the advantages of preparing a presentation directly with it, instead of creating one with LibreOffice Impress. 
I would like to see a very good example of a presentation in Mathematica to have an idea of the advantages of doing one with it.

Comment: This is a possible subset of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61/best-way-to-give-presentations-with-mathematica

Comment: Also Stephen Wolfram gives piles of talks, mostly advertising Mathematica, but you can look at what he does. It seems he tends not to use the actual slideshow functionality, but I can attest to its utility.

Comment: If you want ideas of what to do with WL, check these Stephen Wolfram presentations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjCWdsrVcBM, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OMBSGBHlzk, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YJhzTJm62s

Comment: If you want to use Mathematica as a slide show, I would recommend not to use it as a PowerPoint/Impress static presentation but using the notebook to do some livecoding. Of course, you would need to rehearse your coding.